# Pass a parameter to youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I want to pass the `--ignore-errors`([link](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options)) parameter to my youtube-dl object and i can't seem to be doing it right.
Here's the code:

```
options = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'ignore-errors': True,
'postprocessors': [{
    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    'preferredquality': '192',
}],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as youtube_object:
    meta = youtube_object.extract_info(link, download = False)
```

One of the videos from the playlist i'm trying to download gives me an error and i should like to ignore that video(exactly what the cmd --ignore-error does) but how can i integrate it in a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option you need is [`ignoreerrors`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/a03a3c80fe7174e200af32425a77bfa2bde980d8/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L164)

Easiest way to see mapping from command-line params to "in-code" is to look into [cli spec](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/f19eae429a2c999db143060fded506dc52aaa398/youtube_dl/options.py#L144). Its based on build-in optparse lib, and you're looking for [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.dest) argument.

Comment: i'm trying it now. Is there a rule i'm not getting about converting the CMD option commands in script commands?

Comment: I've added info on this to answer. No particular rule, and afaik, `youtube-dl` does not give any public docs on this. But in-code documentation for class should be enough, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, i ll accept it as soon as it will let me:)